# Should logger.exception only be called inside an except block? Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, logging

The docs for [`logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) mention:

> This method should only be called from an exception handler.

So usage should look something like this:

```
try:
    errorerrorerror
except NameError as e:
    logger.exception('debug message %s', e)
```

But when I tried doing it the "wrong" way, behaviour seemed to be just the same:

```
try:
    errorerrorerror
except NameError as e:
    pass

logger.exception('debug message %s', e)
```

What is the reason for that caveat mentioned in the docs?  Is it *actually* true that we can only use it in an except block, for some subtle reason not evident here?

Comment: *should* != *must*. The intention is for it to be used in an exception handler as it'll grab the last raised exception from the current thread.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but _should only_ == _must_.  And apparently we can still grab the last raised exception outside the block, no?

Comment: No, the *only* doesn't make it equal to *must*. You can replace `should` with `must` and change the meaning, or you could emphasise `should` (make it italics or bold) and still have the same interpretation.

Comment: And yes, you can still grab the raised exception outside of the block. I linked to the `sys.exec_info()` documentation in my answer, where it explains exactly what it can and cannot do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method is *designed* for use in an exception handler. As such the documentation tells you this, by using the word *should*, not *must*.

In the text of standards, *should* and *must* are rigidly defined; one means *we advice you to do it this way, it'd be much better if you did*, the other means *it's an outright error if you don't do this*. See [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) for the IETF taskforce wording.

All `logging.exception()` does is set the `exc_info` keyword argument before calling `logging.error()`. The `exc_info` argument is then later fleshed out to include the *most recently handled exception*, taken from [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). It is then up to the formatter to include the exception message (via the [`Formatter.format_exception()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException)) to format the exception.

Because `sys.exc_info()` works both in the `except` suite and out, both variants work. From a *code documentation point of view*, it is just clearer if you use it in the `except` handler.

You don't need to include the error message, really, because your log formatter should already do that for you:

```
logger.exception('debug message 2')  # exception should be included automatically
```

You can explicitly attach an exception to any log message with:

```
logger.error('debug message 2', exc_info=sys.exc_info())
```

or any other 3-tuple value with the exception type, the exception value and a traceback. Alternatively, set `exc_info=1` to have the logger retrieve the information from `sys.exc_info()` itself.

See the documentation for [`Logger.debug()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug):

> *exc_info* which, if it does not evaluate as false, causes exception information to be added to the logging message. If an exception tuple (in the format returned by `sys.exc_info()`) is provided, it is used; otherwise, `sys.exc_info()` is called to get the exception information.

Comment: My actual use case is wanting a `logger.exception` call after multiple except blocks, without having to put the same line into every except block.

Comment: @wim: you can do that just fine with this.

Comment: what about raising custom exceptions? What would be a good approach then? i.e. `logger.error("some err msg"); raise MyCustomError` or `logger.exception("some err msg", MyCustomError)`

Comment: @bluesmonk: custom exceptions are no different from the built-in exceptions, you'd use `logger.exception()` or  `exc_info` just the same.

Comment: @bluesmonk: `logger.exception()` is designed to be used in the error handler, where you caught the exception, not where you raised an exception. Same for `exc_info`, it is meant to log an exception that was caught.

Comment: I don't agree with the preamble here- the Python docs are not an RFC, and I think we SHOULD NOT say that the RFC 2119 wording applies to Python documentation  ;)   They're just using casual language, and the words should be interpreted as plain English. The answer is good otherwise..

Comment: @wim: the wording actually comes from [PEP 282](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/#loggers), and I _think_ that has a history going back to Java loggers log4j and JSR47 but I can't find now anything more concrete than [the original project page](http://web.archive.org/web/20020408082952/www.red-dove.com/python_logging.html). But you are right, it isn't really an RFC. We _could_ try ask the [package author himself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118903/vinay-sajip)..

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour is not really the same.  The function logs the last raised exception, but only within an `except` block you can be sure this exception is actually the one happened in the `try` block belonging to the `except` block.  Your example has an exception that *always* happens.  In that, quite useless, corner case it really doesn't matter if the `log.exception()` call is done in the `except` block or after it.

---

Two examples to illustrate the difference:

```
import logging
import random

try:
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        1 / 0
except:
    logging.exception()
```

versus:

```
import logging
import random

try:
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        1 / 0
except:
    pass

logging.exception()
```

In the fist code there is a 50% chance a `ZeroDivisionError` happens, which is the logged.  In the second code there is the same chance of the exception happening and it is logged if it happens.  Now think what happens in the other 50% of the runs.

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer the actual question.  In my [sscce](http://sscce.org/) I didn't bother checking there was an exception because it was obvious it is guaranteed - in my actual code I set a flag for exception raised (and there are multiple except blocks), and check the flag before logging exception.  But this was not relevant information to the actual question.

Comment: @wim You asked for the reason why the docs suggest using it just within `except` blocks.  And I gave a reason and and example.  That this doesn't match your specific use case and extra code not shown in your example I hardly could have guessed.

Comment: @wim: On second thought: It's not an sscce then if you leave out the flag.